# Laravel Count from another table

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a problem and im using laravel 4. I want to display the list of schools and then as the school are listed, it will also display the total number of teachers from that school wherein teachers are found in another table. is it possible to achieve that using the eloquent orm?.

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge there isn't, what we've been doing is something like this:

In your School model:

```
public function teacherCount()
{
    return Teachers::where('school_id', $this->id)->count();
}
```

Comment: hi @duellsy, thanks for the quick reply. but i think that code will cost a lot of query request, if the school is 100 the query will take 100 as well.. am right with that? sorry for my innocence with this coz im really new in laravel 4

Comment: In this case you should consider adding a teacher_count index to your school that you should update when you change the teachers.  This way you'll be able to get the count without querying the teachers' table

Comment: it will be one extra query, that is correct, however the question asked for an Eloquent response, that's the closest I can come up with. As Phil said, a workaround for this would instead be to keep your own count, just be sure to increment / decrement correctly otherwise you'll get out of sync